# How do I simply create a connection to a remote mySQL database with ASP.NET VB

Tags: mysql, .net, webforms

I've scoured the web for a few days now, All I want to do is connect to a db, add a record, and close the connection. Thats it, I dont need to pull any data or populate any lists or tables. Simply add a record.

with classic asp I could do this with my eyes close... but this seems like the hardest thing I've come across yet. Its a remote mySQL Database.

I'm using webforms with .net, The script is complete, have loaded all form entries into variables ready to put into my SQL statement for whenever I manage to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a connection string in your web.config like so:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Use:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyRemoteDb"
      connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Ref.  http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: After scowering some more, The thing tripping me up was that I could do this in web.config, in the codebehind, or in the datasource control itself.